# Shared stuff across whole application in Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I'm not asking about repairing my code or something I've just have a problem on where to or how to put methods in proper places in my application.
I wrote an application enhancing bluetooth chat - I made service for this bluetooth chat that runs in background. I will have more such services. Basically I want to be able to run methods  across whole my application:

- send message via bluetooth chat and wait for answer,
- scan RFID tag with NFC,
- scan Barcode with camera,

etc.

Each of this I know how to do in 1 activity easily. Now I'm looking for a solution to put this in something like a global class that will allow me to call this methods across my whole application - so I don't have to initialize anything but just - doSomething() and it does it.
Where should I put such things:

- in custom activity class (all my other activities will use it)?
- in application?
- something else?

The same applies to handlers. Basically as to bluetooth chat you have to make handler to listen to received messages - where to put it as well.

I'm basically looking for propositions on how to solve this.

Comment: I'm not an android programmer but assuming it's the same as core java you can create static methods to do all this and then (if you really must) do a [static import](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=195) so you don't need to do Class.doSomething(); but thats rarely wise and you shouldn't do it excessively

Answer (score 0):

You can have one BaseActivity that extends activity and put your common functions in BaseActivity, now extend all other activities with BaseActivity.

Your activity will have these functions available.

For example:

```
class BaseActivity extends activity{
...........

public void sendMsgViaBluetooth(String msg){
...........
}

}



class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{

<OnSomeEvent>{

sendMsgViaBluetooth(msg);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class with some static methods that allows you to obtain instances of certain classes handling different functionality. You can create a listener system where multiple activities can register themselves for events, such as received messages. When the main class then receives something, it will go through all listeners, and inform them.

Otherwise, you can also send broadcasts, and let those activities interested listen for them. A problem here though is that no one is listening, messages might be lost. When you handle it yourself, in case no one is listening you can store messages in a queue, and send them when new listeners register.

I would not go with the BaseActivity idea. The bigger your app gets, the harder this becomes (e.g., what if you want a Fragment to do things as well, a service that should obtain something, or when you want to implement other classes that require to extend anything else than Activity).

Answer (score 0):

To have data/methods that "follows" you all over the scope of your application, create a Class that extends Application. You have to specify in your Manifest that this Class will be your Application class.

```
android:name="com.example.MyApplicationClass">
```

After that, you can call getApplication() to get the Application context and cast it to your Class

```
myAppContext = (MyApplicationClass)getApplication();
```

Try avoiding Singleton pattern. I've done one in an application and when the app became big enough, my singleton would get erased sometimes (when resuming the application after coming back from launcher). The application context is supposed to keep the data even if the application is in background for a long time.